# How to extract email address from heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku

I have a heroku app @ www.bstorm2014.com. I used the hobby-dev database option. Now I would like to extract the email address of all the registered users. I need to do this to send them the latest info about our event. How can I extract all the email address? I tried

```
heroku run rails console
>User.all(:email)
```

But its not working. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the pluck method.

```
User.pluck(:email)
```